# Send email report sonar scanner in jenkins

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

Please help Me getting result of sonar scanner in jenkins to send email report.

I can get sonar scanner's id:

`${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.sonar.action.SonarAnalysisAction').getCeTaskId()}`

But I dont get any status process .

(I am using ext-email report)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to get quality gate status. You know that an important part of the analysis (like measure aggregation and quality gate check) is made on SonarQube server asynchronously.
We have implemented a Jenkins Pipeline step named `waitForQualityGate()` that will pause your pipeline until processing is done on SonarQube side, and return the quality gate status.

If you want to do something similar for an old style Jenkins job, you'll have to implement something similar on your own. For now we don't plan to backport this feature. The main reason is that doing this "wait" in a normal Job will occupy a slave for nothing.